# Disable preliminary lock screen background Windows Server 2016

Tags: desktop-customization, windows-server-2016

When I open up my virtual machine of Windows Server 2016, I'm greeted with an image of a cave with the time and "press ctrl + alt + del". How do I go about removing the image of the cave and replacing it with a solid colour / no background at all?

I've attempted a regedit hack to remove the background of the actual lock screen, which worked, but this is nevertheless not the screen I'm referring to.
The only option in *Lock Screen* in *Settings* is to change the picture to another picture, not a solid colour. All the advice I've read seems to be detail how to completely disable it, however I wish to keep the initial screen, and simply remove the picture. Is this possible?

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the personalization menu with the screen I am referring to and the dropdown detailing that there is no option for solid colour.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: [You have to use the group policy to disable the lock screen.](http://www.howtogeek.com/110283/how-to-disable-the-lock-screen-in-windows-8/).  This policy can only be changed for Windows Server, Windows Enterprise, and Windows Education SKUs.  
[Disable Lock Screen in Windows 10 / 8.1 & Windows Server 2016 / 2012 (R2)](https://techjourney.net/disable-lock-screen-in-windows-10-8-1-windows-server-2016-2012-r2/)

Comment: @Ramhound, on other threads people note mixed results using the GP.

Comment: @music2myear - Other threads people were not using Enterprise, Education, or Windows Server.

Comment: OP doesn't want to disable the lock screen, just remove the selected/default background image from it and replace it with a solid color.

Comment: So why did you make your first comment?

Comment: Because there are GPs for changing the lock screen image, and people have noted mixed results on that, and I mistakenly assumed that's what you were linking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Rewriting to answer the actual question instead of my (incorrect) assumptions:**

On a fresh Windows Server 2016 installation I used Paint to create a solid color image and saved it to the Desktop; either PNG or JPG will work.

Then I opened the **Personalize** settings window and opened the Lock Screen section.

With **Background** set to **Picture**, I clicked **Browse** and selected the image I'd just created.

Then I logged off and confirmed that the image was now set as the Lock Screen background. I also rebooted and confirmed the same image showed up again both on the lock screen and the logon screen.

**NOTE:** If your organization is enforcing GPs preventing the lock screen from being changed, this may prevent you from changing the picture.

Comment: This works perfectly for the actual logon screen. I am referring to the screen with the time displayed on it which occurs before the logon one.

Comment: In googling, others reports more or less the same thing.

Comment: Oh, hmmmm.... I wonder if one can replace one of these "accepted" images with one of a solid color. I've done this trick with the XP login message box many years ago. Lemme do a bit of research.

Comment: Ok, in that picture I see there is still the "browse" button below the images. I don't have a Server 2016 box spun up yet to test for certain, but I built a quick black jpg in Paint and then selected this picture as the new logon screen image, and it worked. Can you test this?

Comment: @ShiffleMcDoobles did this work for you?

Comment: Yes this works, it's a shame it's not as easy as simply choosing a colour from a palette similar to how the desktop colours work. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: That would make sense, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

The following guide only applies to Windows Server 2012+, Windows 10 Enterprise, and Windows 10 Education.  *The group policy in question has no effect on Windows 10 Professional when running build 14393 Version 1607 aka Windows 10 Anniversary Update*

> 1. Open Local Group Policy Editor (GPedit.msc) by searching for it.
> 2. Navigate to the following branch:
>
>    Local Computer Policy -> Administrative Templates -> Control Panel -> Personalization.
> 3. In the right, double click or double tap on Do not display the lock screen setting.
> 4. Select Enabled radio button.
> 5. Click or tap OK when done.
> 6. Exit from Local Group Policy Editor.
> 7. You may need to restart the computer for the change to take effect.
>
> [image]
>
> 1. Run Registry Editor (RegEdit) by searching for it.
> 2. Go to the following Registry key:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
>
> If “Personalization” registry key is not found, create it by right
>   clicking on
>
> 3. Windows, and select New -> Key.
> 4. Create a new a DWORD (32-bit) value named **NoLockScreen**.
> 5. Set its data to **1**.
> 6. Exit from Registry Editor.
> 7. You may need to restart the computer for the change to take effect.

If you save the following code as a .reg file you can make this change automatically:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
"NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001
```

Source: [Disable Lock Screen in Windows 10 / 8.1 & Windows Server 2016 / 2012 (R2)](https://techjourney.net/disable-lock-screen-in-windows-10-8-1-windows-server-2016-2012-r2/)

Comment: This answer is gear specifically to a user running Windows Server 2016 and/or Windows 10 Enterprise/Education.  I provided a note that, the group policy has no effect on Windows 10 past (and including) build 14393.  *This behavior is well documented and there is already a question, with an answer, that explains a work around so I didn't talk about it*

Comment: I will be honest. Its not clear if you want to disable the lock screen entirely or just change the background.  I am not sure how you "disable" the background, something has to be the background, when enabled it will either be an image or a solid color.  Just create an image that is a solid color, if you just want a solid color, seems to be simplest solution on that side of the coin.

Comment: Question notes he is trying to remove the background image from the lock screen, not remove the lock screen itself.